# Replace fragile option with \scantokens for beamer frames

Tags: beamer, tex-core, verbatim, forward-inverse-search

When there is some verbatim code inside a beamer frame, we need to use `fragile` option. But this `fragile` option often makes inverse search jump to wrong file.

Therefore I tried to replace `fragile` option with `\scantokens` command in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
\scantokens{\begin{verbatim}
#1
\end{verbatim}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Before
\mycmd{
  \hello \world
}
After
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The above code indeed works. Now I want to define an environment rather than a command, but the following code causes an error.

```
! File ended while scanning text of \scantokens.
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{%
   \scantokens\bgroup\verbatim
}
{%
   \endverbatim\egroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Before
\begin{myenv}
  \hello \world
\end{myenv}
End
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What is the correct way to define such environment?

Comment: do you use luatex (makes the answer a bit easier if you do)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use xelatex.

Comment: No, the “command version” doesn't work: it won't preserve line endings, for instance. Do you know about the `semiverbatim` environment of `beamer`? Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't work for a couple of reasons.

### First reason.

The syntax for `\scantokens` is

```
\scantokens <general text>
```

and a `<general text>` can start with an implicit brace, but cannot end with it: the termination *must* be an explicit brace.

### Second reason

Line endings are managed before `\scantokens` does its job, so they're lost. Also your code with the command form will suffer of this problem. For instance

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
\scantokens{\begin{verbatim}
#1
\end{verbatim}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Before
\mycmd{
  \hello \world
  \hello \world
  \hello \world
}
After
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

### Conclusion

You're doomed, sorry. There's no escape from the `fragile` option.